# Unable to get user input from input field and assign it to another div's innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I know that this question sounds silly but i am curious why i can avoid this problem in JavaScript. Now in the code below i have given :

```js
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function get() {
  var x = document.getElementById("text").value; // --> HERE 
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x;
};

get();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">

<p id="para"></p>
```

Now when i assign the variable x inside the function ,after the ("text") i get the  .nodeValue instead of getting the .value. Is that a problem with my code editor or i have an error, because every time i put a name inside the input field it shows the result inside the paragraph it appears and fast also disappears

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask, but I get `ReferenceError: get is not defined`.

Comment: @melpomene thats because the get is not defined in this scope, but only assigned to `btn.onlick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I see 2 problems here:

- You didn`t close your script tag.
- You are calling get(); but the function does not exist in that scope but is only assigned in the onclick event.

This should do the trick:

```js
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function get() {
  var x = document.getElementById("text").value;
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="HELLO">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">

<p id="para"></p>
```

I have preset the value to "HELLO", but you can change it as you want, and it will deliver the value requested when clicking on the button.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only problem may have been how you were declaring the event listener, I declared it as an event listener on the button listening to the 'click' event.

I also edited 'x' to be 'userInput' so it is more clear what it is trying to achieve.

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("text").value;
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = userInput;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var btn=document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function () {
  var x = document.getElementById("text").value; // --> HERE 
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x;
};

btn.onclick()
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text" value="hello">
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn">

<p id="para"></p>
```

This is a working example of what you are trying to do. You can't declare a function in that context as it's anonymous. My example works perfectly, but you should do something more like

```
function get() { 
//Do something
}
btn.onclick = get;
get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this will solve or not. However, I suggest you by giving an `onclick` event inside the input tag.

```
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="btn" onclick="get()"> 
    <script>
    function get() {
    var x = document.getElementById("text").value; 
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = x;
    }
    </script>`
```